# django-parler translations for abstract model

Tags: python, django, django-parler

My django app must be translatable, static pages and models too. For translating models I'm using django-parler app. This works fine, but for simple models, I mean, models that doesn't inherits from an abstract model class.

Let's say that we have a Vehicle abstract model

```
class Vehicle(TranslatableModel):

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and a child model which is Car:

```
class Car(Vehicle)
    """..."""
```

This raised me this error: **TypeError: Can't create TranslatedFieldsModel for abstract class Vehicle**.

I'd like still using django model inheritance. So, what can I do for translating my models using django-parler, it support translations for abstract models or I'll need to use another app to achieve this, in that case any suggestion on any?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, parler implicitly creates an extra db table for the translations which has a `ForeignKey` to the model that the translated fields are declared on. You cannot have a FK to an abstract model because it does not have its own db table. What if you have two models subclassing this abstract model? Which table is the translation table's FK pointing to?

You could try to implement the translatable fields outside of your model if you want to share the same translatable fields across models and still be relatively DRY:

```
vehicle_translations = TranslatedFields(
    description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
)

class Car(TranslatableModel):
    translations = vehicle_translations
```

Comment: How can I put another field translations? translations2 = another_base_class_translation.

Comment: More translations will be hard to add, I admit :)#

Comment: It still throws the same error in my case. Does django-parler support use with abstract classes or is there an alternative package I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `TranslatedField` as explained in the docs: https://django-parler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/parler.fields.html#the-translatedfield-class

Comment: I am having this same problem but I don't want to use `TranslatedField`. How can I go about this?